# MySQL query to find *best* row per group where *best* is a complex metrics

Tags: mysql

My table `foobar` has the following columns:

`val: tinyint NOT NULL
date: timestamp NOT NULL
type: enum('A', 'B', 'C') NOT NULL
extra: tinyint NOT NULL`

For each `type` I would like to find the row that matches an arbitrary condition on the columns (e.g. `extra > 12 AND val > 0`), that minimizes `val` and, in case of equal `val`, minimizes `date`. I assume that for each `type` such a row exists and is unique. Finally, I'd like the result (as many rows as there are different `type` values) to be ordered by `val`, `date`.

If `foobar` contains the following rows:

```
+------+---------------------+------+-------+
| val  | date                | type | extra |
+------+---------------------+------+-------+
| -1   | 2014-04-10 00:00:00 | A    | 40    |
|  1   | 2014-04-15 00:00:00 | A    | 15    |
|  2   | 2014-04-12 00:00:00 | A    | 77    |
|  1   | 2014-04-11 00:00:00 | A    |  2    |
|  1   | 2014-04-14 00:00:00 | A    | 22    |
|  1   | 2014-04-10 00:00:00 | B    | 40    |
|  1   | 2014-04-15 00:00:00 | B    | 15    |
|  1   | 2014-04-12 00:00:00 | B    | 77    |
|  1   | 2014-04-11 00:00:00 | B    |  2    |
|  1   | 2014-04-14 00:00:00 | B    | 22    |
|  4   | 2014-04-10 00:00:00 | C    | 40    |
|  3   | 2014-04-15 00:00:00 | C    | 15    |
|  3   | 2014-04-12 00:00:00 | C    | 77    |
|  1   | 2014-04-11 00:00:00 | C    |  2    |
|  3   | 2014-04-14 00:00:00 | C    | 22    |
+------+---------------------+------+-------+
```

the query shall return:

```
+------+---------------------+------+-------+
| val  | date                | type | extra |
+------+---------------------+------+-------+
|  1   | 2014-04-10 00:00:00 | B    | 40    |
|  1   | 2014-04-14 00:00:00 | A    | 22    |
|  3   | 2014-04-12 00:00:00 | C    | 77    |
+------+---------------------+------+-------+
```

This seems to work:

```
SELECT a.* FROM (
    SELECT MIN(val * 4294967296 + UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)) AS score
        FROM foobar WHERE extra > 12 AND val > 0
        GROUP BY type
    ) AS b
INNER JOIN foobar AS a
    ON a.val * 4294967296 + UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a.date) = b.score
ORDER BY val, date;
```

but I find it over-complicated and I suspect that there must be a better way. Moreover, transforming my multi-columns criteria in a single numeric value (`val * 4294967296 + UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)`) works in this simple case but may be more difficult in more complex scenarios.

Are there other, more generic schemes, that would do the same?

Comment: `I assume that for each type such a row [...] is unique.` This needn't be an assumption. It can, and should, be explicit in the definition of your table. Also, note that in MySQL, the number in parentheses following an integer data type is almost meaningless.

Comment: @Strawberry: Very interesting. Can you please explain how to add such a complex unique condition: only one row per value of `type` such that `extra > 12 AND val > 0` and `val` is minimal and if more than one such row exists there must be a unique smallest `date`? One or two keywords would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(val INT SIGNED NOT NULL
,date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
,type CHAR(1) NOT NULL 
,extra TINYINT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(val,date,type)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(-1,'2014-04-10 00:00:00','A',40),
( 1,'2014-04-15 00:00:00','A',15),
( 2,'2014-04-12 00:00:00','A',77),
( 1,'2014-04-11 00:00:00','A', 2),
( 1,'2014-04-14 00:00:00','A',22),
( 1,'2014-04-10 00:00:00','B',40),
( 1,'2014-04-15 00:00:00','B',15),
( 1,'2014-04-12 00:00:00','B',77),
( 1,'2014-04-11 00:00:00','B', 2),
( 1,'2014-04-14 00:00:00','B',22),
( 4,'2014-04-10 00:00:00','C',40),
( 3,'2014-04-15 00:00:00','C',15),
( 3,'2014-04-12 00:00:00','C',77),
( 1,'2014-04-11 00:00:00','C', 2),
( 3,'2014-04-14 00:00:00','C',22);

SELECT a.* 
  FROM my_table a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.val
            , x.type
            , MIN(x.date) date 
         FROM my_table x 
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT MIN(val) val
                   , type
                FROM my_table 
               WHERE extra > 12 
                 AND val > 0 
               GROUP 
                  BY type
            ) y 
           ON y.type = x.type 
          AND y.val = x.val 
        WHERE x.extra > 12
        GROUP 
           BY val
            , type
     ) b 
    ON b.val = a.val 
   AND b.type = a.type 
   AND b.date = a.date;

+-----+---------------------+------+-------+
| val | date                | type | extra |
+-----+---------------------+------+-------+
|   1 | 2014-04-14 00:00:00 | A    |    22 |
|   1 | 2014-04-10 00:00:00 | B    |    40 |
|   3 | 2014-04-12 00:00:00 | C    |    77 |
+-----+---------------------+------+-------+
```